# Cannot display data from the database using id = pk in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to fetch data from the database and display it in view_data.html. I cannot seem to do it. I am not sure if i understand the use case of id = pk at this point. I want to be able to display data containing particular host when i click on the view button under the 'host' Can anyone help me display the data. Here is what I have done so far:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Information(models.Model):
    host = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=False)
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=False)
    port = models.IntegerField()
    platform = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=False)
    groups = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.host
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Information
from .forms import MyForm



def home(request):
  informations = Information.objects.all()
  context = {'informations':informations}

  return render(request, 'polls/home.html', context)


def view_data(request, pk):
  information = Information.objects.get(id=pk)
  context = {'information':information}

  return render(request, 'polls/view_data.html')


def my_form(request):
  if request.method == "POST":
    form = MyForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      form.save()
      return redirect('home')
  else:
      form = MyForm()
  return render(request, 'polls/room_form.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Information

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Information
    fields = '__all__'
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('view_data/<str:pk>/', views.view_data, name = "view_data"),
    path('host/', views.my_form, name='my_form')


]
```

home.html

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}

{% block content %}

<h1>Home Template</h1>



<div>

    <a href="{% url 'my_form' %}"> Add Device </a>
    <hr>

    <div>
        {% for information in informations %}
            <span>@{{information.host}}</span>
            <h3>{{information.id}}<a href="{% url 'view_data' information.id %}"> view </a></h3>
            <hr>

        {% endfor %}


    </div>


        

</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

viewdata.html

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}

{% block content %}



<h1>{{information.hostname}}</h1>




{% endblock content %}
```

Edit: I forgot to send the context in my view_data. The problem is solved now.

Comment: See if changing `path('view_data/<str:pk>/...'` in your path to `path('view_data/<int:pk>/...'` makes a difference.  The `id` or `pk` in your case is an `int`.

Comment: Thanks for the input @raphael but i already tried that and it did not work.

Comment: Ok.  I think you forgot to send the `context` in your `view_data`.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on how <str:pk> is able to access the precise data from the database. I do not think I fully understand.

Comment: When a user visits the path `view_data/234/` for example, the path `view_data/<int:pk>/`, specifically the `<int:pk>` tells it that the 234 is an `int` that it should take in as the `pk`.  The path finds the view responsible for creating the HTML responsible for that url path, which in this case is `def view_data(request, pk):`.  The *same* variable must be used in the view as in the url path.  Where did the made up 234 come from?  The HTML, `<a href="{% url 'view_data' information.id %}">` which says to go to the url named `view_data` with the `information.id` as the parameter.

Comment: Hmmn I understand that part but how does pk actually fetch the data from the database since I have not defined the key in my database.

Comment: `pk` is the primary key.  If you don't define it, Django creates it for you as the `id`.